# How to pass laravel variable in vuejs router link?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2

I'm trying to pass laravel variable in Vuejs router link but it is not working.How i can pass user id in router link?

```
<ul>

    @foreach($children as $child)

        <li>
            @if($child->user_type == 'user')

                <script>
                    var UserId = '{{ $child->id }}';
                </script>

                <router-link :to='"/dashboard/" + UserId' class="nav-link-text mb-1">
               {{ $child->user_name}}</router-link>

            @endif

        </li>

    @endforeach

</ul>
```

Comment: https://dev.to/aligoren/passing-data-to-a-router-link-in-vuejs-2cb0

Comment: @AlecJoy This is not what i need

Comment: have you tried just doing :to="/dashboard/{{$child->id}}"?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your blade views will *always* be constructed, executed and completed before your Vue application is started on the client, so, just like **@Alec Joy** mentioned in his comment, it'll be easier to directly add the ID in the link.

Your blade code will end up generating:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <script>
            var UserId = '1';
        </script>

        <router-link :to='"/dashboard/" + UserId' class="nav-link-text mb-1">Bob</router-link>

    </li>
</ul>
```

In this case, the UserId is superfluous, since you are assigning a Javascript variable to be used in one spot. It  is better to have, in this case, the User ID hardcoded into the routerlink from the blade file.

Change your blade file to:

```
<ul>
@foreach($children as $child)
    <li>
    @if($child->user_type == 'user')
        <router-link :to="/dashboard/{{ $child->id }}" class="nav-link-text mb-1">{{ $child->user_name}}</router-link>
    @endif
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: It just changed the id which passes in router-link. Can we force the component or we can refresh the component?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You may need to expand on what it is you are expecting to achieve

Comment: It changes the id only but not loading the content against that id

Answer (score 0):

Handling dynamic data can be done in two ways.

1. As URL Path variables
2. As Query parameters
3. As Parameters over the browser history ( a hidden mechanism )

Passing data to components as URL path variable or Query Params

https://techformist.com/url-params-vue/

Try this if you want to have a dynamic data passed to the component over the route link using params (a hidden mechanism).

https://dev.to/aligoren/passing-data-to-a-router-link-in-vuejs-2cb0

Hope this helps.

Or [read more on Vue documentation: Dynamic Routing](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html).

Answer (score 0):

for requried perameter

```
<router-link v-bind:to="{name : 'showproduct' , params : {id:1}}">
```

for conditional perameter

```
<router-link v-bind:to="{path:'/indexpage' ,query: { name: 'hello' }}">
```